# Plot and Display Bitmap from Matrix

Tags: java, android

I am new to Java-Programming for Android and working on a presumambly simple issue. I have an array of 25 integers which represent the colors of 25 pixels. I am trying to create a 5x5 Bitmap from this using Bitmap.createBitmap and display it in an ImageView.

I am using the ARGB_8888 Color-Coding which uses hex for RGB+A (translucency) in the following manner:
int color = (A & 0xff) << 24 | (B & 0xff) << 16 | (G & 0xff << 8 | (R & 0xff).
So am I right that the color black with no translucency should be 0?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

All documentation that I found was about transforming (scaling and rotating) bitmaps using matrices.

```
package com.example.fingerpaint;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Bitmap picture;
    int[] colors = new int[25];
    int width;
    ImageView Image;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        Intent mIntent = getIntent();
        width = mIntent.getIntExtra("width", 0);

        for(int k = 0; k<25; k++){
            colors[k]= (0 & 0xff) << 24;
        }
        picture = Bitmap.createBitmap(colors,5,5, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Image.setImageBitmap(picture);
    }
}
```

When executing the app on my android device, no error appears and no ImageView (should be a small black square) is visible.

Comment: Please only use the tag android-studio for questions referring to the IDE Android-Studio.

Comment: "So am I right that the color black with no translucency should be 0?" – No. `0` is completely transparent. Solid black is `0xff000000`, or `-16777216` in decimal. You want to change your color calculation to `colors[k] = 0xff << 24;`.

Comment: Some smaller remarks: If you where to replace the `android-studio` tag by `android` you would attract the attention of other Android programmers that might help you with your `ImageView`. Another thing is the naming of your variable `Image`, variables should always start with a lower case character, only classes start in upper case.

Comment: Thank you Mike M. for the help on the color issue. That solved it. Also thank you to GameDroids for the advice.